# Components randomly resize and move when I run my app on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I inherited an FMX Android project from a coworker. My job is to redesign the forms. I haven't worked on an Android app yet, but so far trying to lay out my forms has been frustrating. Everything looks perfect in the IDE, but when I run the app on my tablet, everything moves or resizes to crazy proportions.

For example, I want to have a Title bar on the top of every page in the app that tells the user which form they are viewing. So I:

1. Place a panel on my form
2. Set align to Top
3. Set the height to 60
4. Set anchors to top, left, and right
5. Add a label to the panel with a page name
6. Set the label's align property to Contents

In the IDE, it now looks perfect. I run the app and that top panel expands WAY down the page, covering up literally 75% of the screen. Instead of the height being 60px like I set it to, it's more like 700px now!

I've had many other instances where things were lined up nicely in the IDE but after running the app it seems like their positions jump all over the place.

What could be happening to cause this and how do I fix it?

Comment: you can check this youtube channel. Maybe you will learn something 
https://www.youtube.com/@blangkonfa5124/videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing FMX user interface always make sure you are working with correct Design View selected.

Then when your application is executed it tries to load the design view that is most suitable for your target device.

[image: Design View]

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was an issue with Views, but was a little different for me. The specialized view was not in that list. Instead, it was created in a separate form and then linked into the primary form with a line like `{$R *.T390.fmx ANDROID}` at the beginning of the Implementation section. I deleted the extra T390 form and that line in the primary form and it worked perfectly. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: So the problem was that when your application was compiled it did not include the default design time created form definitions which Delphi stores in FMX file but instead a custom FMX file. Do you perhaps know which Delphi version had been your coworker using? Based on the name of FMX file I'm guessing the view was intended for Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 2. And when I compare the release dates of Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 2 and release dates of Delphi I'm guessing Delphi 10.2 perhaps Delphi 10.3. ...

Comment: ... You may want to recheck all of the views that your project support since their naming style has definitely been changed in recent Delphi versions, so you avoid similar problem when launching your application on other devices. You may also want to read more about [Adding Views to Your Multi-Device Project](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Adding_Views_to_Your_Multi-Device_Project) in order to better understand how multiple views work and consequently why you have been encountering this problem.